# Sonar 3.0 installation error

Tags: sonarqube

I've installed Sonar 3.0 to my server machine, but this error code is generated..

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/05/09 15:05:31 | --> Wrapper Started as Console
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/05/09 15:05:31 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:31 | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:31 |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:31 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:31 | 2012-05-09 15:05:31.792:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:31 | 2012-05-09 15:05:31.823:INFO::jetty-6.1.25
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:31 | 2012-05-09 15:05:31.933:INFO::NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
2012.05.09 15:05:32 INFO  o.s.c.p.Database  Create JDBC datasource
2012.05.09 15:05:32 ERROR o.s.s.p.Platform  Error resolving class . Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'Integer'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: Integer
org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class . Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'Integer'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: Integer
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.BaseBuilder.resolveClass(BaseBuilder.java:69) ~[mybatis-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLStatementBuilder.parseStatementNode(XMLStatementBuilder.java:40) ~[mybatis-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.buildStatementFromContext(XMLMapperBuilder.java:108) ~[mybatis-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.configurationElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:98) ~[mybatis-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.parse(XMLMapperBuilder.java:75) ~[mybatis-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.MyBatis.loadMapper(MyBatis.java:136) ~[sonar-core-3.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.MyBatis.start(MyBatis.java:87) ~[sonar-core-3.0.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) ~[picocontainer-2.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) ~[picocontainer-2.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169) ~[picocontainer-2.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132) ~[picocontainer-2.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009) ~[picocontainer-2.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1002) ~[picocontainer-2.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:760) ~[picocontainer-2.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:70) ~[sonar-plugin-api-3.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startDatabaseConnectors(Platform.java:150) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:99) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformLifecycleListener.contextInitialized(PlatformLifecycleListener.java:33) [classes/:na]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1272) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:489) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50) [jetty-util-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50) [jetty-util-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
    at org.sonar.application.JettyEmbedder.start(JettyEmbedder.java:72) [sonar-application-3.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.application.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:48) [sonar-application-3.0.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240) [wrapper-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_04]
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'Integer'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: Integer
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeAliasRegistry.resolveAlias(TypeAliasRegistry.java:93) ~[mybatis-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.BaseBuilder.resolveAlias(BaseBuilder.java:93) ~[mybatis-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.BaseBuilder.resolveClass(BaseBuilder.java:67) ~[mybatis-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: Integer
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.ClassLoaderWrapper.classForName(ClassLoaderWrapper.java:173) ~[mybatis-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.ClassLoaderWrapper.classForName(ClassLoaderWrapper.java:72) ~[mybatis-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.classForName(Resources.java:235) ~[mybatis-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeAliasRegistry.resolveAlias(TypeAliasRegistry.java:89) ~[mybatis-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 | 2012-05-09 15:05:32.603:WARN::Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@1526c5f{/,file:/D:/sonar-3.0/war/sonar-server}
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 | org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class . Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'Integer'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: Integer
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.apache.ibatis.builder.BaseBuilder.resolveClass(BaseBuilder.java:69)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLStatementBuilder.parseStatementNode(XMLStatementBuilder.java:40)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.buildStatementFromContext(XMLMapperBuilder.java:108)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.configurationElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:98)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.parse(XMLMapperBuilder.java:75)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.sonar.core.persistence.MyBatis.loadMapper(MyBatis.java:136)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.sonar.core.persistence.MyBatis.start(MyBatis.java:87)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1002)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:760)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:70)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startDatabaseConnectors(Platform.java:150)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:99)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformLifecycleListener.contextInitialized(PlatformLifecycleListener.java:33)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1272)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:489)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.sonar.application.JettyEmbedder.start(JettyEmbedder.java:72)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.sonar.application.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:48)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/09 15:05:32 | 2012-05-09 15:05:32.603:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9000
```

I installed Sonar on my own laptop, and then I didn't encounter any problem.

Comment: Which DB are you using for Sonar? (and which server? which OS?)

Comment: Damn, that's the first time I see this error... What if you start Sonar with the default configuration (= with embedded Derby database)? Also, can you provide us with more information on how you configured Sonar to connect to MySql? (the properties you've set, the driver, ...etc)

Comment: I was normally start Sonar in my own laptop, but in server i got this error record. I tried with embedded Derby and mysql, this error didnt change. I'm sure no defect for configuration.

Comment: Are you installing Sonar on a separate server like Tomcat?

Comment: This problem was solved to change O.S' language. Turkish language was problem!!

Comment: @UsTa please post your solution as an answer (as detailed as possible).

Comment: I installed O.S that has an english language

Comment: @UsTa Post as an answer, not a new comment :) Nice one by the way!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, as you guessed, this is related to your system's character encoding.

You can solve the problem by adding the below Java Additional Parameters to conf/wrapper.conf

```
wrapper.java.additional.3=-Duser.language=en
```