# Jenkins Triggering a Sonar Analysis with the Sonar Runner

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonar-runner

I want to jenkins triggering a sonar Analysis with the Sonar Runner, but I get an error message, what can I do,what's the problem, please help me, thanks. (I installed jenkins,sonar and sonar runner)

Error Detail; (from jenkins)

```
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\Sonar_Runner\Sonar_Runner_2.0\bin\sonar-    runner.bat" "-Dsonar.projectBaseDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\E-Power\workspace" -    Dsonar.fxcop.assemblyDependencyDirectories=/bin/Debug -Dsonar.dotnet.version=4.0 -    Dsources=C:/Users/eazakli/Desktop/sonar-runner-2.0/sonar-runner-2.0/test -Dsonar.language=cs -    Dsonar.stylecop.mode=skip -Dsonar.gendarme.mode=skip -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0 -    Dsonar.gendarme.assemblies=build\DmgTech*.* -Dsonar.projectKey=EA:TESTEA -Dsonar.gallio.mode=skip -    Dsonar.dotnet.4.0.sdk.directory=C:/WIndows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319 "-    Dsonar.fxcop.installDirectory=C:/Program Files/Microsoft FxCop 1.36" -Dsonar.projectName=E-POWER
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\Sonar_Runner\Sonar_Runner_2.0
Runner configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\Sonar_Runner\Sonar_Runner_2.0    \conf\sonar-runner.properties
Project configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\E-Power\workspace\sonar-    project.properties
Runner version: 2.0
Java version: 1.6.0_35, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
OS name: "Windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86"
Default locale: "tr_TR", source code encoding: "windows-1254" (analysis is platform dependent)
Server: http://localhost:9000
Work directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\E-Power\workspace\.sonar
14:33:54.737 [main] WARN  o.s.r.i.batch.SonarProjectBuilder - /!\ The 'sources' property is     deprecated and is replaced by 'sonar.sources'. Don't forget to update your files.
14:33:56.420 WARN  .c.p.DefaultDatabase - H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
14:33:56.421 INFO      o.s.c.p.Database - Create JDBC datasource to url     jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/sonar
Total time: 8.119s
Final Memory: 2M/15M
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.RunnerException:     org.picocontainer.PicoLifecycleException: PicoLifecycleException: method 'public     org.sonar.core.persistence.MyBatis org.sonar.core.persistence.MyBatis.start()',     instance 'org.sonar.core.persistence.MyBatis@1a4ded3, org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException:     Error resolving class . Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'Integer'.  Cause:     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: Integer
at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:288)
at org.sonar.runner.Runner.execute(Runner.java:151)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:84)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:56)
Caused by: org.picocontainer.PicoLifecycleException: PicoLifecycleException: method 'public     org.sonar.core.persistence.MyBatis org.sonar.core.persistence.MyBatis.start()',     instance 'org.sonar.core.persistence.MyBatis@1a4ded3, org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException:     Error resolving class . Cause:     org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'Integer'.  Cause:     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: Integer
at org.picocontainer.monitors.NullComponentMonitor.lifecycleInvocationFailed    (NullComponentMonitor.java:77)
at     org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.monitorAndThrowReflectionLifecycleException    (ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:132)
at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod    (ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:115)
at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter    (DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1002)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:760)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:70)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:82)
at org.sonar.batch.Batch.execute(Batch.java:104)
at org.sonar.runner.internal.batch.Launcher.executeBatch(Launcher.java:69)
at org.sonar.runner.internal.batch.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:61)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:285)
... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class . Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'Integer'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: Integer
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.BaseBuilder.resolveClass(BaseBuilder.java:94)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLStatementBuilder.parseStatementNode(XMLStatementBuilder.java:83)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.buildStatementFromContext(XMLMapperBuilder.java:128)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.buildStatementFromContext(XMLMapperBuilder.java:121)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.configurationElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:111)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.parse(XMLMapperBuilder.java:88)
at org.sonar.core.persistence.MyBatis.loadMapper(MyBatis.java:177)
at org.sonar.core.persistence.MyBatis.loadMappers(MyBatis.java:154)
at org.sonar.core.persistence.MyBatis.start(MyBatis.java:121)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'Integer'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: Integer
at org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeAliasRegistry.resolveAlias(TypeAliasRegistry.java:109)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.BaseBuilder.resolveAlias(BaseBuilder.java:115)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.BaseBuilder.resolveClass(BaseBuilder.java:92)
... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: Integer
at org.apache.ibatis.io.ClassLoaderWrapper.classForName(ClassLoaderWrapper.java:188)
at org.apache.ibatis.io.ClassLoaderWrapper.classForName(ClassLoaderWrapper.java:87)
at org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.classForName(Resources.java:250)
at org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeAliasRegistry.resolveAlias(TypeAliasRegistry.java:105)
... 36 more
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following error tends to show that the installation of your Java environment is not correct:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: Integer
```

You should look into this direction.

Comment: How can I change? (It is not working in jenkins but work fine standalone)

Comment: Maybe Jenkins is run as a Windows service, with a different Windows user? (and this user doesn't have a properly configured environment)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the  [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515599/sonar-3-0-installation-error) related with almost same error.

Solution was to "Add Java Additional Parameters to *conf/wrapper.conf*" given by @Erkut Evirgen

```
wrapper.java.additional.3=-Duser.language=en
```